# Weird things happen when I try to kill a Thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this "Serial" class that extends Thread that works with a serial port. In the run() method I first open the port, set all the Serial params and add a SerialPortEventListener. Then i just put a while(go) where go is a private (so only the class can see it) boolean instance set as true. I have a kill method that not only it closes the port and remove the SerialEventListener, but also set "go" as false, hence the Thread should stop. Now, here is where things start getting weird: if I put a System.out.println(something) in the while(go), when I call the kill() method the Thred stops, but if I doesn't it remains alive. Do you have any ideas about why it works like that and how to solve it?

```
while(go) {
            System.out.println("in");
        }
```

```
public void kill(){
        go = false;
        try {
            this.serialPort.removeEventListener();
            this.serialPort.closePort();
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should *never* access the same variable from two threads without protection. It's a recipe for disaster, as you've already discovered. You need some form of [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: And how do I do that? Can I just add the synchronized word to the kill() method?

Comment: You need to synchronize *all* access to the variable, not just the modification in `kill`. When you access it in `run` it also needs to be synchronized (using a block, *not* the whole method; if you synchronize the whole `run` method you'll never be able to call `kill`)

Comment: Thank you for your time, would you please provide me a sample code please? Just so you know, I only acces the variable "go" in the while(go) (which is in the method run()) and in kill()

Comment: [The section on sleep and yield](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) in the Java Language Specification explains it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to arguing about the way you implemented those thread. However, lookig at the specific scenario, you have a the `Serial` class, which stays alive and does its job as long as the variable `go` is `true`. The same variable can also be changed by another thread (i.e. the main one) once the method `kill` is invoked.
As suggested by @WJS, the best approach to make the things work properly, is to declare the variable `go` as "volatile". You should have something like that:

```
public class Serial extends Thread {
   ...
   private volatile boolean go;
   ...

   public void kill(){
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Basically, in this way, the JVM makes sure that different threads read a consistent value of the variable, and that actually it's what happend in a multithread scenario like yours.

Another approach is to define the variable go as `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`, instead of having it as simple primitive `boolean`. That also works very well in this situation, because in this way every change of the variable's value is guaranteed by the JVM as being an atomic operation, which means made it "at ones", and you will always avoid any possible race condition.
In this case, you code should be something like that:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
...
public class Serial extends Thread {
    private AtomicBoolean go = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    ...

    public void loop() {
        ...
        while(go.get()) {
        
        }
    }
 
    public kill() {
       atomicBoolean.set(false);
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Unless `go` is declared volatile, there is no guarantee the while loop (or anything else) will read the current value.

declare go as

```
volatile boolean go;
```

Then it should work (unless there are other things going on that haven't been posted).  And doing this does not alleviate the requirement to do proper synchronization.

Comment: Good thing: it works just fine. Bad thing: I don't know what "volatile" means and I don't know how to do the synchronization, would you please help me out?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is an involved subject and would take too much time.  But you can check out this section at [Java Tutorials - concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) that discusses how to properly synchronize threads.  The keyword `volatile` is covered under the section on `atomic access`.  There are other sources on the web too.  And you can always come back to SO and ask questions on this when specific issues arise.  And you can also search SO for the topic of `synchronization` as it has been covered many times before.

Comment: @DavidePasero To be blunt, if you do not understand `volatile` (and the `Atomic…`  classes) you should *not* be doing threaded/concurrent programming. Read the Oracle tutorials, search and study posts on this site, and most importantly, read the classic book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://jcip.net/) by Brian Goetz, et al.